# Logstash pipeline not working with csvfile

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

set it up like below

```
wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/logstash/logstash-6.6.2.deb
sudo dpkg -i logstash-6.6.2.deb
sudo systemctl enable logstash.service
sudo systemctl start logstash.service
```

and i added a pipeline script like below

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/root/dev/Intuseer-PaaS/backend/airound_sv_logs.log"
                start_position => "beginning"
        }
}
output {
        stdout {}
        file {
                path => "/root/dev/output/output-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
        }
}
```

the log file likes below

```
timestamp, server_cpu, server_memory_used, server_memory_free, process_cpu, process_memory
1582787287, 1, 1176, 2759, 0, 9.05
1582787288, 1, 1176, 2759, 1, 8.97
1582787289, 2, 1176, 2759, 0, 9.04
1582787290, 1, 1177, 2758, 0, 8.98
1582787291, 0, 1176, 2759, 1, 9.04
1582787292, 1, 1176, 2759, 0, 8.96
1582787293, 1, 1177, 2758, 0, 9.03
1582787294, 1, 1176, 2759, 1, 9.08
1582787295, 0, 1177, 2758, 0, 9.02
1582787296, 1, 1176, 2759, 1, 9.05
```

I've tried so many time to get this log on local directory. I checked the status of logstash. but It doesn't have change after below. aslo the output-%.log file wasn't made.

The result of $ systemctl status logstash.service
[image: the result of $ systemctl status logstash.service]

Please help me. thank you.
[image]Im trying with logstash 6.6.2. I

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34228807/4604579 (hint: you need to add the `sincedb_path` setting)

Comment: @Val Thank you for your coment. But I already tried like below
input {
        file {
                path => "/root/dev/Intuseer-PaaS/backend/airound_sv_logs.log"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}
output {
        stdout {}
        file {
                path => "/root/dev/output/output-%{+YYYY-MM-dd}.log"
        }
}
But It doesn't have change.

Comment: Can you show the logs from when you started logstash after you added that setting?

Comment: @Val Of course.
after start
[logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50}
[logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline started successfully {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x3818b992 run>"}
[logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[filewatch.observingtail  ] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}

Comment: @Val It's pretty same with the screen shot.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I'm not certain that Logstash can either read or write files in /root. Can you run logstash from the command line (instead of via the service) like this: `bin/logstash -f file.conf --debug`

Comment: @Val Something working! but how can I show you this?

Comment: @Val Updated the issue with screen shot.

Comment: Then it looks like it's working. Have you checked your output file `/root/dev/output/output-2020-02-27.log` ?

Comment: @Val I can see the logfile now. but what is difference $ sudo systemctl start logstash.service and bin/logstash -f file.conf --debug ?? I didn't see any changes with   $sudo systemctl start logstash.service

Comment: no difference `--debug` simply prints out a little bit more logs so you can see what's going on. I think it's always been working, but the fact that the log was quiet made you think that it wasn't working.

Comment: Now you just need to leverage the [`csv` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) in order to parse your rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, in summary, everything was working, but since you didn't see anything in the log you assumed it wasn't working. Adding `--debug` confirmed that everything was working properly.

A few notes, though:

- Don't forget to add `sincedb_path` otherwise you run the risk of not being able to reprocess your file repeatedly
- Try not to do stuff in /root as the use under which Logstash runs might not always have the right to R/W that folder
- Leverage the [`csv` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html) in order to parse your rows.