# Logstash not reading log file but reads text file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk, logstash-file

The contents of my log file is same but it does not read the file in .log extension but is able to read it in .txt extension

Config for reading .txt file :-

```
input{
    file{
        path => ["/home/viggy/dummy/eppm.txt" ],
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
```

Config for reading .log file :-

```
input{
    file{
        type => "log",
        path => ["/home/viggy/dummy/eppm.log" ],
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228174/logstash-unable-to-read-json-from-text-file/34228807#34228807 ?

Comment: Doesnt work already tried it.

Comment: Also note that you're missing a double quote in your path. Can you share the Logstash logs when your pipeline starts?

Comment: Its just a typo sorry. ill correct it.

Comment: Can you share the Logstash logs when your pipeline starts?

Comment: how to i check logs ?

Comment: How are you starting Logstash?

Comment: Solved the issue the date was added automatically in the file name. eg eppm.log.2021-01-15. it was just a naming issue. Thank you for your help

Comment: Glad you figured it out!