# logstash seems not working and there is no output

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using logstash 7.10.1, and I have following configuration:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:/tmp/logstash/1input.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    ignore_older => 0  
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "D:/tmp/logstash/1output.txt"
  }
}
```

I have a text file `D:/tmp/logstash/1input.txt` with some text in it, and  then I run the following command:  `logstash.bat -f D:\tmp\logstash\1conf.conf`

Then the command stuck with the following log, no further progress.

```
[2021-03-22T15:58:13,621][INFO ][filewatch.observingtail  ][main][612a1b067e341d2e4bf131f9b6baf2ed90b147f1e3ad0186784aedf03c28855a] START, creating Discoverer, Watch with file and sincedb collections
[2021-03-22T15:58:13,640][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2021-03-22T15:58:13,875][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

I checked the output,and the output file `D:/tmp/logstash/1output.txt` is not here.

I would ask where the problem may be, thanks!

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34228807/4604579 (hint: add `sincedb_path`)

Answer (score 0):

For each launch of logstash process, this one keep a kind of 'pointer' in a file to be able to restart the reading of a file when it've been stopped before. So you must have launch before our logstash and for him, the file 1input.txt hase been read before. To fix this, you must set the parameters called "sincedb_path", to force logstash to not keep his state.

Official doc about this parameters [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path).

So in your case, this must look like this :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "D:/tmp/logstash/1input.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
    ignore_older => 0  
  }
}

output {
  file {
    path => "D:/tmp/logstash/1output.txt"
  }
}
```